# Popup not on mobile browsers

Tags: jquery, browser, mobile-website

I have jquery popup which opens on all browsers from mobiles and pc. i don't want to show it on mobile browsers so how can i do that ?

```
function lightbox(){
$.colorbox({inline:true, href:"#inline_content",onClosed: pauseSound, overlayClose: false});
            }
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to detect a handheld device in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function lightbox(){
if (screen.width <=700) #or whatever you want
  {
  $.colorbox({inline:true, href:"#inline_content",onClosed: pauseSound, overlayClose: false});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery) you can do this

```
function lightbox(){
  if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    return;
  }
  $.colorbox({inline:true, href:"#inline_content",onClosed: pauseSound, overlayClose: false});
 }
```

Comment: like i don't want to open popup on mobile browsers but i think using it will also not open popup on tablets.

Comment: Last time I looked, most tablets use mobile browser :)